# What is the sound of one argument permuting?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, logic, definition, determinant

A function $M:\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)^{k}\to\mathbb{R}$, written $M\left[\mathfrak{a}_{1},\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{k}\right]$; where $\mathfrak{a}_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is said to be *k-multilinear* on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if it is linear in each of its arguuments. It is said to be *alternating* if

$$M\left[\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{i}\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{i},\dots\right]=0.$$

That is, if any pair of arguuments are equal. Or, equivalently, if interchanging a pair of arguments reverses the the arithmetic singn of the function. That is, if 
$$M\left[\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{i}\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{j},\dots\right]=-M\left[\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{j}\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{i},\dots\right].$$

For example, $D:\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)^{n}\to\mathbb{R},$ the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix written as a function the column vectors

$$D\left[\mathfrak{a}_{1},\dots,\mathfrak{a}_{n}\right]=\left|\begin{bmatrix}a_{\cdot1}^{1} & \dots & a_{\cdot n}^{1}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{\cdot1}^{n} & \dots & a_{\cdot n}^{n}
\end{bmatrix}\right|,$$

is such a function.

Edwards condescends:

> Notice that every linear function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is automatically alternating.

How do I interchange or make equal a pair of arguments in the function $L\left[\mathfrak{a}\right]\in\mathbb{R}$?

Or, why should I conclude that a "1-multilinear function" is althernating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no pair of distinct arguments, so the alternating hypothesis is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: All men are mortal. Socrates is a memory.  Not a man.

Comment: @StevenHatton Is that a joke, or a comment on the meaning of entailment, or both? Either way, I don't get it.

Comment: A commuting pair of arguments requires a pair of arguments.  Call functions with 2 or more arguments which reverse sign when a pair of arguments is commuted.  That a function is "mortal" shall be defined by the assertion that commuting a pair of arguments reverses the sign of that function.  Call a particular man "Socrates".  Socrates is a man.  Therefore Socrates is mortal.  Call a function that takes one argument a dog.  All men are mortal.  Therefore a dog is mortal?

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've never met an immortal dog...

Comment: I can't tell from your comments if you're happy with vacuous truth (in which case, my answer should satisfy you), or if you're confused by it (in which case, start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), or if you're some kind of skeptic (in which case, you'll have a lot of trouble reading mathematics or communicating with mathematicians).

Comment: Since this vacuous reasoning appears to be acceptable to some mathematicians, I will accept the answer.   I guss this is why the empty set is both closed and open.  But not neither closed nor open.  If I "understan" correctly.

Comment: Not some, *all* mathematicians. There's no controversy about it: according to the very meanings of $\forall$ and $\rightarrow$ in mathematics, the statement $\forall x\,(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is *true* whenever there are no $x$ which satisfy $P$, no matter what $Q$ is. The fact that the empty set is both closed and open has nothing to do with vacuous truth (it's just part of the definition of topological spaces), but vacuous truth is the reason why the empty set is a subset of every set.

Answer (score 1):

A multi linear map is alternating for all possible inputs $v_1, \ldots, v_k$, if $v_i = v_j$ for $i \ne j$, then $M(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = 0$. For $k=1$, the hypothesis of this statement is always false so the statement that every linear map is alternating is vacuously true.